# Experiencing error with Math.max and parseInt

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

In the following function, my code returns `NaN`, instead of a number. This function basically calculates the length of the first longest string consisting of `k` consecutive strings taken in the array - `strarr`.

```
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {  

    var n = strarr.length;  
    if(n === 0 ||  n < k || k<=0){  
      return "";  
      }  
      else{  
      var arrI = [0,0,0,0];  
      var max;  
      for (var i = 0; i<(strarr.length - k); i++){  
        for(var j = i; j<(i+k); j++){  
          arrI[i] += strarr[j].length;  
          }  
        }  
          max = arrI.indexOf(Math.max(arrI));  
          return Math.max(arrI) //typeof(arrI[i]) for i {0,1,2,3} returns 'number' and arrI.length returns 4  

          }  
}  

console.log(longestConsec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"],    2), "abigailtheta")
```

In the above function , my code returns NaN, instead of a number.
    This function basically calculates the length of the first longest string consisting of k consecutive strings taken in the array - strarr.   But if I replace the `return Math.max(arrI)` line with `return Math.max(parseInt(arrI))` then my code works fine.

My question is that it shouldn't matter because `arrI` is an array of numbers , not string but apparently it does. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) isn't defined as taking an array, it's defined as taking discrete arguments.

If you want to apply it to an array, you can: `Math.max.apply(Math, arr)`. In ES2015+, you can also use spread notation: `Math.max(...arr)`

The reason it didn't give you `NaN` when you threw `parseInt` at it was that `parseInt` coerces its argument to string, and then parses the beginning of that string, stopping with the first invalid character, and returning what it had so far. When you coerce an array to string, it coerces each entry to string and then joins them with commas, so for instance `[1, 2, 3, 4]` becomes `"1,2,3,4"`. `parseInt` will parse `1` out of that. In effect, you were doing `Math.max(arr[0])`, which isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `Math.max` takes each number as an own parameter: `Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4...)`. That's why `Math.max(arrI)` is NaN. What you want is the following: `Math.max.apply(null, arrI);`.